# Tampermonkey JavaScript jQuery how to find and edit elements of an embedded web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, embedding, tampermonkey

How to access a web page after having embedded it into a div? Trying normally just returns null. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var replaceThis = document.querySelector('.div1');
var withThis = document.querySelector('.div2 a').getAttribute("href");
replaceThis.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="' + withThis + '" style="width: -webkit-fill-available; height: -webkit-fill-available;"></object>';

var thingFromEmbeddedSite = document.querySelector('.div2'); //returns div2
console.log(thingFromEmbeddedSite);

thingFromEmbeddedSite = document.querySelector('h2'); //returns null
console.log(thingFromEmbeddedSite);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zhhL9rjr/3/

Comment: @is it from same domain?? i mean, the site that you are embedding belongs to same domain??

Comment: Yes, it's from the same domain.

Comment: As per my understanding, if it belongs to same domain then you can use iframe instead of object, then try it `console.log($(".div1 iframe").contents().find("html").html());` .Let me know it is working or not??

Comment: I get "VM8873:53 Uncaught TypeError: ".div1 iframe".contents is not a function at window.onload". I think it's interpreted as text.

Comment: Have you used iframe instead of object?? I think you are testing it in jsfiddle. Apply this into your own application.

Comment: Yes, tried iframe and I need it for a Tampermonkey script. I'll add that to the title. Here's what I tried anyway https://jsfiddle.net/zhhL9rjr/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to wait for the content to load and then access the content, i have made a small update to your fiddle, it does not work in there due to cross-origin.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        stuff
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/">link</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function embed(src, target){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = src;
        iframe.style = "width: -webkit-fill-available;height: -webkit-fill-available;";
        iframe.onload = function(){
            resolve(iframe.contentWindow.document);
        };

      target.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, target);
   });
}

let href = document.querySelector('.div2 a').getAttribute("href"),
    target = document.querySelector('.div1');

embed(href, target).then(function(doc){

    console.log( doc.querySelector('h2') );

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zhhL9rjr/6/

but should work if you load something from the same domain.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there a way to get it to wait until the content is loaded without setting an arbitrary time delay?

Comment: with the code above the promise is resolved as soon as the iframe is done loading.

Comment: It looks like without timeout the doc part runs between `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 59ms` and `[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 82ms`. Is there a way to track those and run something after them?

Comment: you could use a `MutationObserver` and execute some code when it detects that an element you are looking for is in the DOM.

Comment: I thought I figured it out, I changed `iframe.onload` to `document.ready` for the resolving functin, but now it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: hard to tell you without knowing what type of content the iframe holds, if the content you try to get is generated after load by a script or something.

Comment: It should have images with broken links which my script would fix. Adding `// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js` seems to have made it work, but now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` in the console. Those seem to be the results of the site's own javascript.